# search location when we enter zipcode using google api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This my code but its not working :

```
  var geocoder;
  var map;

  function initialize() {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-28.397, 189.644);

     var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  //Call this wherever needed to actually handle the display
  function codeAddress() {
     var zipCode = document.getElementById("address").value;
     alert("zipCode" +zipCode);

     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipCode}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           //Got result, center the map and put it out there

           map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
           });
        } else {
           alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
     });
  }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `codeAddress()` or are you calling it in somewhere?

Comment: yes we are calling in html page

Comment: <input id="address" type="textbox" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress();">
    <div id="map-canvas"/>

Comment: You should add that into your question and also share what is the error, are there any error information on console or does it alert as _Geocode was not successful..._?

Comment: actully sir its show location but not accroding to zip code like if  we giv input 160018 this is Chandigarh ZipCode but its show Singapore

Comment: You can use component filtering with `country` set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A zipCode isn't unique across the world. When you want to restrict the result to a given country use, as  Anto Jurković said, the componentRestrictions:

```
{ 'address': zipCode,componentRestrictions:{country:'in'}}
```

result: [**`(30.7332254,76.78702899999996)`**](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q=30.7332254,76.78702899999996)